# Oracle SQL Developer: Failure - Test failed: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

### Problem

Please note that I changed details for security purposes. However, the problem remains intact.

I installed an Oracle 11g database on a server at location, say, herp-devDV.derp.edu. 
Now I have another Oracle 11g database on a server at location, say, derp-db.derp.edu.

I entered the connection name, username, password, hostname, and service name in Oracle SQL developer for both herp-devDV.derp.edu and derp-db.derp.edu. I can connect to schema in derp-db.derp.edu, but not herp-devDV.derp.edu. It gives me this message:

```
Failure - Test failed: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

### Details

I have the following information:

- Port 1521 is not open for either server when I telnet
- My listener is up and running for both.
- I can access derp-db.derp.edu on Oracle SQL Developer.
- Oracle client is on my local machine + Oracle SQL Developer
- I can remote desktop to both servers

### What I have done

- Googled
- Stackoverflow
- Ran stop and start lnrctl commands
- On herp-devDB.derp.edu I ran `lsnrctl status`

I received the following output

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                03-JUN-2014 13:37:22
Uptime                    6 days 0 hr. 53 min. 4 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   D:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         d:\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\HERP-DEVDB\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=HERP-DEVDB.derp.edu)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "HERPDEVDBXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "herpdevdb", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "herpdevdb" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "herpdevdb", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

I then check out my listener.ora and find

```
  SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:D:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = HERP-DEVDB.derp.edu)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

At this point, I confess I am scratching my head as I don't see anything sticking out and telling me why this should not be working.

The only clue is when I check derp-db.derp.edu and run the command `lsnrctl status`. Please 
see excerpt below:

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DERP-DB.edu)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
Start Date                18-MAY-2014 02:19:01
Uptime                    22 days 12 hr. 23 min. 18 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
---etc----
```

So I am still scratching my head. Why would derp-db be connecting to the DERP-DB.edu but herp-devDB is connecting to EXTPROC1521? How do I fix this? The listener.ora and other files between these two servers are almost identical except for the name of the instances. 
Hmmm.

- **EDIT1:** I changed the listener.ora in herp. This didn't fix it.
- **EDIT2:** I cannot telnet into derp-db.derp.edu on port 1521. But I can still connect to it with SQL Developer? Wth?
- **EDIT3** I cannot telnet into herp-devdb.derp.edu on port 1521 either.
- **EDIT4** I cannot ping IP addresses of either server.

Anyway assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Regards, 
Geeky

Comment: Can you telnet to herp-devDV.derp.edu on port 1521 from your client machine?  Is the Oracle client installed on your client machine or just SQL Developer?

Comment: @JustinCave I edited my question to address your questions. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does `HERP-DEVDB.derp.edu` resolve to the same IP address from your client and from the server? Or to put it another way, if you do `netstat -an | find "1521"` on the server does it show that port on the IP address you expect? You mentioned changing your `listener.ora`; presumably you restarted the listener afterwards?  (And where does `HERP-DEVDB.users.campus` fit in; is that just obscured differently, or does it resolve to the same address too?)

Comment: The first thing I would try, is to add the database to the tnsnames.ora on your machine and then try to run tnsping. If that works, all the ports are open, if not you need to check the firewall settings on the db server and your machine.

Comment: @AlexPoole It does show the port on the ip address I expect.

Comment: @Gisli That got me somewhat further. I can connect to derp-db.derp.edu. However, for herp-devdb.derp.edu I get TNS-12535: TNS:operation timed out.

Comment: Then it really sounds like you have a firewall blocking port 1521, somewhere between your client and server, or on one of them. (The only odd thing is telnet not working to `derp-db`; that maybe suggests a fireall/antivirus on your client that's blocking at the application level. But then telnet would never work to any host or port). Running a traceroute to both servers *might* give a hint of where the block is, but you might need your network people to monitor a connection attempt to pin it down.

Comment: I thought I'd add an additional step that I hadn't thought of initially: my work VPN connection had dropped without my knowledge. It dawned on me to check after landing on this page, FWIW.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWdODgQwE6k  ..look at this

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am answering this for the benefit of future community users. There were multiple issues. If you encounter this problem, I suggest you look for the following:

- Make sure your tnsnames.ora is complete and has the databases you wish to connect to
- Make sure you can tnsping the server you wish to connect to
- On the server, make sure it will be open on the port you desire with the specific application you are using.

Once I did these three things, I solved my problem.

Comment: Where is the tnsnames.ora is located? and how do i know it is complete?

Comment: @Lucky SOMEPATH\app\<user>\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN

Comment: Verify your "listener.ora" file (is it pointing to the right hostname?). Verify also if your Oracle TNSListener service is running. This answer helped me to find a way. Now mine is working fine.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue where I also continuously got the same error. I tried many things like changing the listener port number, turning off the firewall etc. Finally I was able to resolve the issue by changing listener.ora file. I changed the following line:

```
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
```

to

```
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname)(PORT = 1521))
```

I also added an entry in the `/etc/hosts` file.

you can use Oracle net manager to change the above line in listener.ora file. See Oracle Net Services Administrator's Guide for more information on how to do it using net manager.

Also you can use the service name (`database_name.domain_name`) instead of SID while making the connnection.

I Hope it helps.

Answer (score 9):

I solved this by writing the explicit IP address defined in the Listener.ora file as the hostname.
[image]

**So, instead of "localhost", I wrote "192.168.1.2" as the "Hostname" in the SQL Developer field.**

In the below picture I highlighted the input boxes that I've modified:
[image]

Comment: where is this file located?

Comment: @RitikKumar It's located in ORACLE_HOME/network/admin, where ORACLE_HOME is the home directory of your oracle db. On my machine, it's located in C:\app\elyas\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE. To find where your ORACLE_HOME is located, follow these steps:
1) open CMD.
2) run "sqlplus / as sysdba".
3) execute these: a) "var OHM varchar2(100);" b) "EXEC dbms_system.get_env('ORACLE_HOME', :OHM);" c) "PRINT OHM"

Answer (score 6):

I just had same issue when I installed the oracle 11g and then creating the database.

I don't even know that the listener has to create manually.
Hence, I open Net Configuration Assistant and manually create the listener.

And I can connect the database that I created locally through sql developer.

Answer (score 5):

You can locate a file named `listener.ora` under the installation folder `oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN`
It contains the following entries

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Codemaker-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

You should verify the HOST (Here it is Codemaker-PC) should be the computer name. If it's not correct the change it as computer name.

then try the following command on the command prompt run as administrator,

```
lsnrctl start
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved just by: given correct host and port
so:

1. Open oracle net manager
2. Local
3. Listener

in Listener on address 2 then copy host to Oracle Developer

finally connect to oracle

Comment: can you please fix typo?

Comment: Where to find Oracle Net Manager?

Answer (score 1):

Curiously, I was able to solve the same issue by doing the exact opposite move to svc's ! I had to :

1) replace the FQDN hostname in my tnsnames.ora / listener.ora files with **localhost**, and restart the listener service, and

2) two, I had to use "SYS as SYSDBA" as the username in the SQL Developer input textbox

to finally be able to have SQL Developer hook to my local instance.

Answer (score 1):

only start listner then u can connect with database.
command run on editor:

> lsnrctl start

its work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.
I had to turn off my firewall, then it worked.

You could also open the port:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/open-port-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. may help some one. Turn off firewall. on RHEL 7

```
systemctl stop  firewalld
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the HOST was set differently in tnsnames.ora and listener.ora. 
One was set to the full name of the computer and the other was set to IP address.
I synchronized them to the full name of the computer and it worked. Don't forget to restart the oracle services.

I still don't understand exactly why this caused problem because I think IP address and computer name are ultimately same in my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

[Network Adapter could not establish the connection](https://orahow.com/io-error-the-network-adapter-could-not-establish-the-connection/) is very generic error which comes while trying to connect using SQL Developer or application server to the DB server.

Three checks you need to perform.
1: Make sure lsnrctl status is working fine. Crosscheck listener.ora file which is located inside $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin

> lsnrctl status

2: Make sure tnsping is working as expected. Crosscheck tns entry in tnsnames.ora file.

```
tnsping oracle_sid`enter code here`
```

3: Make sure firewall is off. Sometimes firewall block the incoming connection form SQL Developer of app server.

Login as root and check firewall status. If it is up, you can disable it and try.

```
systemctl status firewalld
systemctl stop firewalld
```