# Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: java, oracle

```
import java.sql.*;  
class OracleDBCon
{  
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{  

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  

        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","dypim12345");  

        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  

        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from stud");  

        while(rs.next()){  

            System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+" "+rs.getString(2));  

        }
        con.close();  
    }
}
```

This is my code tried to run on jdk 6, 7, 8 on every version but still getting same error also coppied ojdbc14,5,6 (tried for All ) in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_03\jre\lib\ext but same error please help me with this

same program I run last yr it was woring properly.

Comment: are you not able to connect to oracleDB via Java connector?

Comment: hope this will be useful: https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/connect-to-oracle-db-via-jdbc-driver-java/

Comment: Yes using ojdbc6.jar.  I tried it but again same problem and ? I am using oracle 11g

Comment: oracle DB version 1.2 or 11gR2 -> ojdbc6.jar with JDK 6, JDK 7, and JDK 8 
(Note: JDK7 and JDK8 are supported in 11.2.0.3 and 11.2.0.4 only)
ojdbc5.jar with JDK 5, from here:https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/jdbc-faq-090281.html

Comment: Can any one at lease tell me why this error comes

Comment: Some of the online links: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24127839/2987755, https://community.oracle.com/thread/2547624