# Google Cloud Data Fusion 1. Does not connect to oracle 2. When the pipeline is running I get 'default' network port error

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I installed oracle-jdbc thin driver to connect with On prem oracle DB but when I test the connection I get network adapter error

I tried the changing the host but still same

[image: See below image for error]

When running the pipeline from GCS-BQ I getting network port error. Can we change the VPC the pipeline is running on ?

[image: See below image for error]

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow.  May I suggest that this question be better broken out into two distinct questions ... one for the Oracle puzzle and one for the VPC puzzle?  Our convention is to keep one post to one question ... and questions are free.

Comment: I made it the same question since they are related

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the oracle db connection error, is the db available on the public network for connection? Currently wrangler service in Cloud Data Fusion cannot talk to the on-prem db over a private connection and we are actively working towards it.

However if the db is available on the public network then it seems like the issue with the oracle db configurations. Can you please take a look at this answer and see if it helps - [Oracle SQL Developer: Failure - Test failed: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127839/oracle-sql-developer-failure-test-failed-the-network-adapter-could-not-estab/24267926#24267926)

Also are you able to connect to the oracle db through some other query tool such as SqlWorkbench?

Comment: Can we connect Data Fusion to on-prem Databases now?

Comment: This is not available via public network. It is only available via internal network, we have opened the firewall for this connection. Others tools can connect to this DB from GCP

Answer (score 0):

Breaking down your question:

**1. Connecting to on-prem databases**

It is possible nowadays to connect to on-premise databases. Make sure you created an interconnect between the on-prem network and the network used by Data Fusion instance and make sure you applied the right firewall rules (seems you are getting firewall issues by the logs). I suggest trying to connect directly in the database first to confirm that the network setup works.

---

**2. Change network configurations on the Data Fusion job.**

You can specify parameters for your job. There are options to change the **network** and **subnetwork** that the job will be executed under `Configure > Compute config > Customize` option. If you use shared VPC you can also specify the Host project.

[image]

Comment: I didn't know we can specify private network in data fusion. This is probably why it is running against default network giving error.