# Connecting from Host-SQLDeveloper to Virtualbox VM Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I made a VirtualBox Windows 8 VM Instance with a running 11.2.0.3.0 oracle database.
The Host is an macOS 10.14.6 .
I and trying to connect from the Host to the running VirtualBox VM instance with the database.
I followed this tutorial :
https://learncodeshare.net/2015/05/01/configure-host-access-to-an-oracle-database-on-a-virtualbox-vm/

So I set up a host only adapter :

[Host only adapter configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IPtN.png)

Everything seems to be running fine but I am just not able to connect from my host to this VM Database.
I try to pass the corresponding IP as my hostname in SQLDeveloper as mentioned in the article.

When I try to ping from the host to the VM I get request timeouts as following:

Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1 ...

When I try to ping from the VM to the Host I get:

PING: transmit failed. General failure.

The firewall is offline so I don't think it is an issue.

I already tried using a bridge connection without success.
By default the IP address from the VM is obtained automatically so I tried to use a static IP address also without success.

I also tried to run following commands on the VM without success:

- ipconfig/release
- ipconfig/renew
- ipconfig /flushdns
- netsh int ip reset c:\tcp.txt
- netsh winsock reset

Any hints or help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: just setup a port forward in virtual box, have 1521 on your host go to 1521 on your vm, then in sqldev, you can connect to localhost / 1521 and go straight to your db

Comment: see this, basically the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63562450/oracle-sql-developer-test-failed-the-network-adapter-could-not-establish-the-c/63562944#63562944

Comment: As I mentioned in the other question cited by Jeff, I'm not a big fan of port forwarding for this use. (Sorry, Jeff  :-)  )  I treat my vbox vm's exactly like I would a physical server in my data center, so I want to get to the root of the problem.  For this, I'd want to see the output of 'ipconfig' (or 'ifconfig' - I'm not sure which is used on a Mac) on your host. Then I'd want to see the same from your vm.  You can update your opening question to provide that (and please use copy'n'paste to put it directly in the post, no links to screen shots).

Comment: Thank you guys - the port forwarding worked like a charm.