# How do I connect with my newly created user on Oracle 18c XE?

Tags: oracle

I installed `Oracle 18c XE` and created a new user demo.

For that, I ran the following commands :

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
alter session set container=xepdb1;
create tablespace demo datafile 'demo.dbf' size 1m reuse autoextend on next 1m;
create user demo identified by demo quota unlimited on demo;
grant connect,dba to demo;
```

I created an `tnsnames.ora` entry like this :

```
XEPDB1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XEPDB1)
    )
  )
```

The service `OraceServiceXE` is up but when I connect with demo/demo in sql developer, it says "The Network Adapter could not establish the connection".

- host : localhost
- port : 1521
- SID / service : XEPDB1 (tried both SID
  and service)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127839/oracle-sql-developer-failure-test-failed-the-network-adapter-could-not-estab

Comment: Just as an aside, you should _NOT_ be granting quota on the SYSTEM tablespace.  And along with that, not granting the RESOURCE role.  There should be nothing in the SYSTEM tablespace that oracle itself did not put there, so there is no reason to grant the ability to do so to your own created users.

Comment: @EdStevens question edited, is it fine now ?

Comment: Replace "(SERVICE_NAME = XEPDB1)" with "(SERVICE_NAME = XE)" and try again

Comment: _"question edited, is it fine now ?"_  much better.  Now as to your original question, since you are having a problem connecting with SQL Dev, I'd want to see the connection properties.  Screen shot, pasted into your original question.  And while we're at it, attempt a sqlplus connection.  It's diagnostic error messages are usually more informative than SQL Dev.

Comment: Sorry for not taking the time to come back and update. The problem resides only in the use of localhost rather than IP

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65304046/8315843, I just put the IP address returned by the ipconfig command, in my case 192.168.1.57 instead of localhost, and it solved my issue.